# Generating continuous products or sum

Tags: list-manipulation, automation

This is kind of a continuation of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11815/about-doing-an-integral).

I want to automate these 2 steps on *Mathematica* once I give an integer $N$.

- generate a list of variables $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{i=N}$
- then for some function like $f(x) = e^{x}$ or $f(x) = \sin^2(x)$ compute an expression like $\prod\limits_{i \neq j} f(a_i - a_j)$ or $\sum\limits_{i < j} f(a_i - a_j)$ or $\prod\limits_ {i,j} f(a_i - a_j)$

( - and then hopefully integrate such expressions over all $a_i$...)

I am having to type these expressions by hand for every $N$ and that is very hard once $N$ gets large (one would typically have $\binom{N}{2}$ terms to type by hand!) I would like to know how this can be automated - since I would typically need to to use large $N$.

(...also, help with that previous question would be great!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementing for example $\prod_{j>i}^Nf(a_i-a_j)$:

```
nup = 4;
Times @@ Flatten@Table[f[a[i] - a[j]], {i, 1, nup - 1}, {j, i + 1, nup}]
```

where `nup` is $N$.

Comment: ...or `With[{nup = 6}, Times @@ f /@ Subtract @@@ Subsets[Array[a, nup], {2}]]`